# How to count items in a nested array?

Tags: javascript

I have the following array in my Angular application:

[image]

Each element contains a supplier and one or more products.

How can I get a count of all the products that are returned?

I can get the products themselves by doing this:

```
array.map(x=>x.products)
```

And I can get a count of the products for each element by doing this:

```
array.map(x=>x.products.length)
```

But how do I then sum that?

Comment: how deeply nested can it be?

Comment: Whatever it is make a var and make it increase on each iteration as well as inside iteration. Not that much tough.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to handle this.

```
const totalProducts = arr.reduce((count, current) => count + current.products.length, 0);
```

The concept of `reduce` is to take an array and "reduce" it down to a single entity.  That entity can be an object, another array, number...

The 0 at the end initializes the `reduce` entity.  Since you are going for a sum, set it to 0 and then add to it.

Comment: see details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce