# How to count elements inside all nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, count, nested

I recently started learning JavaScript and ran into a problem. 
 
I wrote a little code that counts elements inside a nested array, but the code breaks when adding an element to the first nested array. I don't understand what the problem is.

```
var clothes = [
    ['cap', 'scarf'],                 //-- When adding a new element, the counter breaks
    ['T-shirt', 'shirt', 'trousers'], //-- When adding a new item, the counter works fine
    ['boots', 'sneakers']             //-- When adding a new item, the counter works fine
];

var totalItems = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < clothes.length; i++) {
        var total = 0;
        for (var k = 0; k <= clothes[i].length; k++) {
            total = total + clothes[k].length;
        }
        return total
    }
};

console.log('all clothes: ' + totalItems());
```

### **Error:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
> at totalItems (test2.js:13)
> at test2.js:31

Please help and explain why the error occurs only when adding to the first nested array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count items in a nested array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56116434/how-to-count-items-in-a-nested-array)

Comment: It is working as expected without any error. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qvs8ndam/)

Comment: @decpk it is only luck that it is working after the edit. With different inputs it still fails or returns incorrect values.

Comment: Then what're the inputs that make it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple issues. Your for loops need to check for `< clothes.length` because `<=` will check an extra value that is not in your array (array's are 0-based, array.length is 1-based). You also are reassigning the total each time through the for-loop, and you are returning from the for loop after going through the loop. Your inner loop also keeps increasing the value of total every time creating numbers that will grow drastically.

This modification will fix all those problems in a much more concise manner.

```
var totalItems = function () {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < clothes.length; i++) {
        total += clothes[i].length;
    }
    return total;
};
```

ES6 way:

```
let totalItems = () => {
    let total = 0;
    clothes.forEach(entry => total += entry.length);
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I still have to learn es6 )))

Comment: I would say learn the basics first, but don't wait too long to learn some of the ES6 stuff. There's a bunch of "new" and very helpful methods that will make your code a lot easier to read, speed up your development and save you from some common errors that you'll encounter writing JS the old way. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
var totalItems = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i <= clothes.length; i++) {
        var total = 0;
        for (var k = 0; k < clothes[i].length; k++) {
            total = total + clothes[k].length;
        }
        return total
    }
};
```

just edit your code like that.Seems like your second for condition looks for not existed index.

Comment: Сounter breaks down and if you add more than 2 elements, then the same error (((

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iterator that will add 1 (***iterator++***) each time the function finds a new value within the nested arrays. I use a ***forEach*** nested within another forEach loop in the example below.

```js
var clothes = [
  ['cap', 'scarf', 'hat'], //-- Added a new element no breaky
  ['T-shirt', 'shirt', 'trousers'], //-- When adding a new item, the counter works fine
  ['boots', 'sneakers'] //-- When adding a new item, the counter works fine
];

var totalItems = function() {
  let total = 0 //<-- iterator
  clothes.forEach(items => {
    items.forEach((item) => {
      total++ // iterate by one each time around
    })
  })  
  return total
}

console.log('all clothes: ' + totalItems());
```